# undefined method for nil:NilClass when render Thinking Sphinx Collection with Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Actually, this is a dumb question, but i'm very confused.

I have a web application with thinking sphinx running on that, these are my models

models/college

```
class College < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :city
```

models/city

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :colleges
belongs_to :state
```

models/state

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :state
```

and here is my indices

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define 'college', :with => :active_record do
  indexes name
end
```

and the problem is when i try to render the search result into view

controller

```
@colleges = College.filter_by_params(params).search params[:keyword]
```

in view I want to print city and state name of the college

```
<% @colleges.each do |college| %>
<tr>
<td>College Name <%= college.name %><td>
<td>City <%= college.city.name %><td>
<td>State <%= college.city.state.name %><td>
</tr>
```

then i got an error undefined method `city' for nil:NilClass

I also try to inspect

```
college.city.inspect
```

and the result is correct !! am I miss something ??

Comment: Irrelevant, but in your state model, shouldn't it be: `has_many :cities`

Comment: `class State < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :state`
It should be like has_many :cities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert `p college` only inside your `@colleges.each` loop. I am sure in one iteration you will get `nil` object. Which causes the error.

Comment: Thanks Priti. thats my fault, i am not check my database yet :)